# Powershell - Make SecureString available for other user

Tags: powershell, securestring

I've an application in which I have to store a password. This application is getting called with the SYSTEM user. I am already obfuscating the script and storing it in a secure location.

Now my question: Is is there any possibility to create a SecureString which can be decrypted by one or more other users?

I've read about the possibility to encrypt it with a key and then store this key in a file, but in my opinion this is nothing else than a obfuscation, because everybody who can access the key file can decrypt the password.

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT: 
To clarify my question: I'd like to know if there is another solution to this than using a key file.

Comment: Q:  Is there any way tp create a SecureString which can be decrypted by one or more other users?  A: Sure.  Encrypt it with a key, and give the "other user(s)" secure access to the key.  Q: Is there any way to encrypt and decrypt a SecureString *without* a key?  A: None that I'm aware of ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's common to know that, if you force a user to enter a secure string, it can be reversed by the person who entered it, using

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$credential.UserName
$credential.Password

# Results
<#
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:

$credential.UserName
testuser

$credential.Password
System.Security.SecureString
#>
```

Or using .Net namespace. So, how about taking the approach of storing the credential in Windows Credential Manager on the user machine. In your app install, you dynamically generate creds to store that you'd then use for execution. Whenever they run your code, your code calls the creds from Credential Manager, without user interaction.

There several modules in the MS PowerShellGallery.com, easily accessed and deployed on systems when targeting credential manager use.

```
Find-Module -Name '*credential*'

<#
Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                           
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                           
2.0                  CredentialManager                   PSGallery            Provides access to credentials in the Windows Credential Manager                      
...
1.0.11               pscredentialmanager                 PSGallery            This module allows management and automation of Windows cached credentials.           
4.5                  BetterCredentials                   PSGallery            A (compatible) major upgrade for Get-Credential, including support for storing cred...
0.0.1                SecureCredentials                   PSGallery            This module allow to secure store encrypted credentials for running powershell daemon 
1.1.7                CredentialStore                     PSGallery            CredentialStore saves powershell credentials securely to file                         
...
1.1                  CredentialsManager                  PSGallery            The module Credentials Manager provides you with convenient and safe way to store y...
...
1.0.2                CredentialManagement                PSGallery            Manage Credentials stored in the Windows Credential Manager                           
1.1.0                PSCredentialTools                   PSGallery            PSCredentialTools provides various methods for securely storing and retrieving cred...
1.1                  New-Credential                      PSGallery            Simply creates an object (System.Management.Automation.PSCredential) that can be us...
...
#>
```

Comment: There's still a "key", and it's still stored on the filesystem ... but it's an excellent suggestion!

Comment: True, but the key would be unique on each new use case, since you could generate a key in the initial startup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @postanote. The CredentialManager approach is a nice suggestion. I'll definitely have a look at it 

Comment: The solution I now use is encrypting the SecureString with a key and then storing this key in the windows credential store using the CredentialManager package. It's still somehow unsafe, but this cannot be 100% safe. It just adds an extra layer of obscurity to it.